# Регулярное выражение для одиночных кавычек

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Задача: нужно найти строки, которые заключены в одинарные `'` кавычки, причём, если перед такой кавычкой стоит слэш `\`, такую кавычку следует пропустить.
Пример:

```
'abc \' def'
```

Я уже прочитал [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739465/regex-match-double-quote-which-does-not-follow-slash-character) на аналогичный случай и попытался переделать данное выражение под свой. Но, как в [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739465/regex-match-double-quote-which-does-not-follow-slash-character), так и в [моём](https://regex101.com/r/vDP154/1) адаптированном регулярном выражении имеется [баг](https://regex101.com/r/dE1zF5/5). Если строка содержит два подряд идущих символа `"` в оригинальном выражении, или `'` в [моём](https://regex101.com/r/vDP154/1), она разбирается некорректно:

```
''value = 'abc \' def'
```

Результатом разбора такой строчки должны быть строки `''` и `'abc \' def'`.

Есть ли вообще возможность сделать это используя только регулярные выражения?

Comment: не знаю как там у вас в java, но в пхп данный рузльтат можно получить с помощью [`(?<!\\)'(?<txt>.*?)(?<!\\)'`](https://regex101.com/r/vDP154/3), хотя я не знаток регулярок, и мб оно будет не корректно работать в других местах. что-то первый раз юзаю просмотры назад.

Comment: На первый взгляд всё верно. Вам стоило оформить это как ответ к вопросу. А в каких местах данное выражение будет работать некорректно?

Comment: да черт его знает, по идее то так, но мало ли :) если подходит, и проходит остальные тесты - оформлю ответом :)

Comment: в частности, если три кавычки подряд, то что это должно быть?

Comment: Если три кавычки подряд, то не должно парсится - будет какая-нибудь ошибка.

Comment: в смысле не может быть в исходных данных такое? или что за ошибка? ибо моя регулярка выводит пустой текст для первой пары, ничего для второй-третьей.

Comment: исли три кавычки подряд, то под регулярное выражение подходят только первые две. Они и должны быть возращены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием *негативных просмотров назад* составил следующее выражение:

```
(?<!\\)'(?<txt>.*?)(?<!\\)'
```

где `(?<!\\)'` обозначает кавычку и *не предшествующий ей слеш*. Далее собственно именованная маска для текста, и опять кавычка с негативным просмотром назад.

Comment: Немного оптимизации: `'(.*?)(?<!\\)'`

Comment: @AleksandrKorotkov если варианта `\''value` не будет, то оптимизируйте :)

Comment: В моей задаче он должен быть разобран именно если \' внутри кавычек. Если снаружи, то пропускаться.